# Issue in displaying text over images in javascript image slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Demo slider</title>
    <link href="themes/1/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="themes/1/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="sliderFrame">
        <div id="slider">
            <img src="images/image-slider-1.jpg" id="img1" alt="" />
            <img src="images/image-slider-2.jpg" id="img2" alt="" />
            <img src="images/image-slider-3.jpg" id="img3" alt="" />
            <img src="images/image-slider-4.jpg" id="img4" alt="" />
            <img src="images/image-slider-5.jpg" id="img5" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="custom_text">
        <h1 style="color: blue;">Image 1 text</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="custom_text1">
        <h1 style="color: blue;">Image 2 text</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="custom_text2">
        <h1 style="color: blue;">Image 3 text</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="custom_text3">
        <h1 style="color: blue;">Image 4 text</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="custom_text4">
        <h1 style="color: blue;">Image 5 text</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using menucool's Javascript Image Slider library: [link to site](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider)

I want to display different text on different images i tried it giving absolute and relative positions to div and img tag but unable to acheive the output.

The javascript slider function is the predefined function.Basically i want to achieve [**this**](http://housing.com/in/indore/new-projects?gclid=CO7--4LSvL8CFVUMjgodVU0A6w)

Comment: What library does the `mcImgSlider` come from? one from [menucool](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider)? It is better to reference a link to an available source, like the main website and/or like a CDN link to the file, then to include it in a code snippet.

Comment: `IF Possible`, create a jsfiddle link. It will always help you getting more help and accurate solution.

Comment: @Popeye unable to create JSfiddle i tried but there is some issue in it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans alright will keep that in mind in future

Comment: @Fresher: Can you share how does your screen looks like.?

Comment: @Popeye Something like [this](http://postimg.org/image/fludwknz7/)

Comment: @Fresher Dude, I am not very sure what changes you have made, but as per my understanding you are using slider from [**MenuCool**](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider#view2). Which has a simple usage. I just created one jsBin using theirs code. [Have a look](http://jsbin.com/ratac/1).

Comment: @Thanks popeye for your effort actually i wanted a different caption but you guided me well

Comment: @popeye just one question though the effects menucool used on images are predefined by them.Can i change them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57146/discussion-between-popeye-and-fresher).

Comment: @Fresher, thats part of the [documentation](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider#jsTitle), hover over "effect", if you mean to customize or make your own effect then you would need to edit their js file, which would be hard as its minified

Comment: @PAtrickEvans ok got it.

Comment: You can choose from any of them given [Transition Effects here](http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo1)

Comment: @Popeye thanks man sorry for wasting your precious time.

Comment: No probs. `@Patrick Evans` is correct, you should read the docs properly before any of us pointing it out.

Comment: @Popeye yes actually i already appologised for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why you always read the documentation:

http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider#view2

> Captions are set through each slide image's   alt   attribute. If the
>   image is formatted as lazy loaded image, its caption can be defined by
>   the   title   or   data-alt   attribute:

HTML

```
<img src="//placehold.it/250x250" id="img1" alt="Caption one" />
<img src="//placehold.it/249x249" id="img2" alt="Caption two" />
<img src="//placehold.it/251x251" id="img3" alt="Caption three" />
<img src="//placehold.it/248x248" id="img4" alt="Caption four" />
<img src="//placehold.it/252x252" id="img5" alt="Caption five" />
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/2Y2d7/2/)

Comment: Thanks man you guided me well.For future i will always read the manual just one question though the effects menucool used on images are predefined by them.Can i change them?